# SharePoint List Custom Display Form Limitation

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Is there any limit on number of fields which can be shown in Custom Display form of SharePoint List? Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

In the fields of the form may be the same number as the number of columns in the list

You can use 8000 bytes per list for site columns.
Columns have different size.

Here you can see size of columns:

[Allow for the maximum number of possible columns in a SharePoint list](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx#Column)